# Efficient way of binning timedeltas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So imagine i have the following timedeltas

```
s = pd.Series({0: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:01.119000'),
 1: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.555000'),
 2: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.282000'),
 3: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.182000'),
 4: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.345000')})
```

And i am trying to formulate a bin column evaluating if they have more than one second

Here it is my approach.

```
l = ['00:00:00','00:00:01']
bins_sec = pd.to_timedelta(l).total_seconds()
cat = ['<1sec','>1sec']
pd.to_timedelta(list(df.s)).total_seconds()
# I dont quite understand why i need to convert my series into a list, so i can get the total seconds attribute
```

Wanted result:

```
s = pd.Series(['>1sec','<1sec','<1sec','<1sec']})
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way of doing such a binning process mine is taking quite a while? Also why doesnt the total_seconds work, with the return of `df.S.total_seconds()`

I get the following error, when i make such attempts

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic method, use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0, 0.5, 1] # seconds

pd.cut(s, bins=[pd.Timedelta(f'{i}s') for i in bins]+[pd.Timedelta.max],
       labels=[f'>{i}s' for i in bins])
```

Output:

```
0      >1s
1    >0.5s
2      >0s
3      >0s
4      >0s
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['>0s' < '>0.5s' < '>1s']
```

Your particular case:

```
pd.cut(s, bins=[pd.Timedelta('0'), pd.Timedelta('1s'), pd.Timedelta.max],
       labels=['<1s', '>1s'])
```

output:

```
0    >1s
1    <1s
2    <1s
3    <1s
4    <1s
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['<1s' < '>1s']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `s.dt.total_seconds()` and np.where

```
from pandas import Timedelta
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series({0: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:01.119000'),
 1: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.555000'),
 2: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.282000'),
 3: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.182000'),
 4: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.345000')})

np.where(s.dt.total_seconds().gt(1),'>1sec','<=1sec')
```

Output

```
array(['>1sec', '<=1sec', '<=1sec', '<=1sec', '<=1sec'], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: You can directly use `np.where(s.gt(pd.Timedelta('1s')), '>1s', '<1s')` ;)

Comment: @mozway That can be simplified even further, see my answer :P

Comment: @BeRT2me yes true, pandas makes a transparent conversion to Timedelta

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Timedelta` in a Series are rather smart, you don't even have to convert them to `total_seconds` to understand the comparison if formatted correctly~

Given `s`:

```
0   0 days 00:00:01.119000
1   0 days 00:00:00.555000
2   0 days 00:00:00.282000
3   0 days 00:00:00.182000
4   0 days 00:00:00.345000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Doing:

```
>>> np.where(s.gt('1s'), '>1sec', '<1sec')
array(['>1sec', '<1sec', '<1sec', '<1sec', '<1sec'], dtype='<U5')

>>> pd.Series(np.where(s.gt('1s'), '>1sec', '<1sec'))
0    >1sec
1    <1sec
2    <1sec
3    <1sec
4    <1sec
dtype: object
```

---

For the categorical route, I'd do:

```
>>> pd.Series(pd.Categorical(s.gt('1s'), ordered=True)
...             .rename_categories(['<1sec', '>1sec']))
0    >1sec
1    <1sec
2    <1sec
3    <1sec
4    <1sec
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['<1sec' < '>1sec']
```